# Running nginx on multiple ports with same rules

Tags: nginx

I'm running nginx on two ports, one for HTTPS and the other for HTTP, but identical in all other ways (i.e. `location` directives, etc.). I'd like to avoid writing the same rules twice.

Is there a way in nginx config files to write my rules in some sort of block and then include them inside my `server` directives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can include extra files into you configuration, see the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) and example below here:

```
server {
  listen              80;
  include             location_directives.conf
}

server {
  ssl                 on;
  listen              443 default spdy ssl;
  include             location_directives.conf
}
```

P.S. By the way, it's prefer to use return 301 to redirect from http to https instead of define the rules for both servers blocks

```
server {
  listen              80;
  return              301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```